# uniform convergence of exponential function on open interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, exponential-function

Let

$$
f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto f_{n}(x) = \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}
$$

Now we know that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$
\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n} = \exp(x) 
$$
pointwise. My question is now, whether the sequence $\{f_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $\exp(x)$

That $f_{n}$ converges uniformly on any compact interval follows immediatley from Dini's Theorem. Does it also converges uniformly on any finite subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You are asking for uniform convergence on the entire real line, right?

Comment: exactly! Maybe the uniform convergence is only satisfied on finite intervals?

Comment: On compacts sure, it does. But if you want convergence on the whole real line, I’m quite sure there isn’t.

Comment: $f_n(n)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108581/uniform-convergence-to-the-exponential-function-over-a-compact-interval and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744506/proving-uniform-convergence-of-1-fracxnn-to-ex-on-compact-intervals

Comment: @Riemann Wait, that shouldn’t be a problem. The issue is that the sup of the difference btw exponential and that function doesn’t go to zero for $n \to \infty$ if you take $x \in \mathbb{R}$, or am I making some trivial mistake?

Comment: but why does it not converge uniformly on any finite open interval?

Answer (score 1):

On the whole real line, no. That’s because for every $n$ you can choose $x$ accordingly so that the difference btw exponential and $(1+x/n)^n$ (basically a polynomial of degree $n$) becomes arbitrarely large.

Comment: You could choose $x=n$ to get $2^n$.

Comment: Ohhh I see what you and the guy in the comments above meant. This way obviously $e^n -2^n$ diverges.

Comment: Yes, I realised that after I added my comment...